# Hide banner Admob - Unity

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, admob

Проблема такова: банер запускается, но не работает Hide(); и Destroy(); у Admobа. 
Скрипт:

```
public BannerView _adMobBanner;

 public void AdmobBannerInizialize()
 {
    _adMobBanner = new BannerView("ca-app-pub-мой ид", AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);
    _adMobBanner.OnAdFailedToLoad += OnAdMobBannerFailedToLoad;
    _adMobBanner.OnAdLoaded += OnAdMobBannerLoaded;
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    _adMobBanner.LoadAd(request);
 }
 public void AdmobBannerHide()
 {
    _adMobBanner.Hide ();
 }
 public void AdmobBannerDestroy()
 {
    _adMobBanner.Destroy ();
 }
 public void Show()
 {
    _adMobBanner.Show ();
 }
```

Скрипт висит на сцене, методы вызываются кнопками UI, пробовал это дело на чистом проекте, там все работает, пробовал заменить плагин, тоже безрезультатно, в чем может быть проблема такого явления ?

Comment: На эмуляторе запускаете?

Comment: нет,запускаю на  Meizu mx6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что не правильно работает. Т.е. когда запускаете на пустом проекте - баннер и показывается и скрывается нормально. Когда запускаете в своём проекте, то баннер показывается нормально, но при вызове Hide или Destroy ничего не происходит? Ошибок никаких не выпадает в консоль? Для того, чтобы отследить логи из запущенного на телефоне приложения можно использовать приложение mLogcat, отфильтровав его логи по тегу Unity. Если что-то упадёт - оно выкинет туда ошибку.

Comment: Проблемой послужило то, что я случайно вызывал несколько инициализаций банера, вместо того что бы сделать одну инициализацию и дальше показывать Show.